# Cassandra & Solr Join 2 Cores

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I've 2 models for Cassandra with the same partition key:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    parent_id int,
    user_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((parent_id), user_id )
);

CREATE TABLE user_actions(
    parent_id int,
    user_id text,
    type text,
    created_at int,
    data map<text, text>,
    PRIMARY KEY((parent_id), user_id, created_at)
);
```

I want to find all the users how made an action and belong to the same parent_id.

Right now I'm getting all the users, even if they did not made an action, I'm using it like this:

```
http://ADDRESS/solr/name.users/select?q=parent_id:1&fq={!join+fromIndex=name.user_actions}type:click
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the query `q=parent_id:1&fq=type:click` return the results you expect when run directly against `name.user_actions`? Also, do you mind posting the version of DSE you're running, along with your schema.xml and solrconfig.xml (or the Solr core creation command, if you auto-generated those)?

Comment: Yes "name.user_actions/select?q=type:action_type" return me the results. I'm using Cassandra 3.10.0.1652 | DSE 5.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are not 'from' and 'to' parameters to tell solr on which fields it should make the join, so your filter query should be something like:

```
fq={!join from=user_id  fromIndex=name.user_actions to=user_id force=true}type:click
```